# spacing in tikz

Tags: spacing, diagrams, arrows, tikz-cd

I'm trying to typeset the naturality property of the cap product, I'm hoping to achieve something like this:

[image]

but the best I can do is something like this:

[image]

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
H_j(X,A\cup B; W) \arrow[d] &\otimes_\mathbb{Z} &H^i(X,A;V) \arrow[r]
& H_{j-i}(X,B;\overline{V} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} W) \arrow[d] \\
H_j(X,A\cup B; W) &\otimes_\mathbb{Z} &H^i(X,A;V) \arrow[u] \arrow[r]  
& H_{j-i}(X,B;\overline{V} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} W) 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
```

I would like to group the two entries on either side of the tensor product at the beginning in a single entry, but then I wouldn't be able to get arrows to and from each one of them individually. I also don't want to change the general column spacing, just have those behave as a single entry but with arrows departing from each one. Thank you very much for any advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reduce the column separation with the `column sep` option. In this case, you can also pretend that the `\otimes` characters are like arrows between two cells, so that you can remove the second column, like so:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
H_j(X,A\cup B; W) \arrow[d] \arrow[r,phantom,"\otimes_\mathbb{Z}" description] &H^i(X,A;V) \arrow[r]
& H_{j-i}(X,B;\overline{V} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} W) \arrow[d] \\
H_j(X,A\cup B; W) \arrow[r,phantom,"\otimes_\mathbb{Z}" description] &H^i(X,A;V) \arrow[u] \arrow[r]  
& H_{j-i}(X,B;\overline{V} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} W) 
\end{tikzcd}
```

As you can see, I replaced `FIRST CELL & op & SECOND CELL` by

```
FIRST CELL \arrow[r,phantom,"op" description] & SECOND CELL
```

The `phantom` option avoid the arrow to be typeset, and the `description` ensures that the operator is placed at the correct position.

[image: Rendered result]

Comment: One last question... do you know how I could typeset something above the horizontal arrows? **Edit** Nevermind, I got it ;)

Answer (score 6):

This requires some manual adjusting, but arrows are standard ones, so they can easily receive labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
H_j(X,A\cup B; W) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} H^i(X,A;V) \arrow[r] \arrow[d,shift right=3em]
& H_{j-i}(X,B;\overline{V} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} W) \arrow[d] \\
H_j(X,A\cup B; W) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} H^i(X,A;V)
 \arrow[u,shift right=5em] \arrow[r]
& H_{j-i}(X,B;\overline{V} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} W)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]